# Sourcing if statement not working as expected in bash

Tags: bash

I got these two scripts

My first script, script1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
question()
{
    q=1
}
main()
{
    question
}
if [ "${1}" != "--source-only" ]; then
    main "${@}"
fi
```

And the second one, script2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./script1.sh --source-only
func()
{
    if [ "$q" = "1" ]; then
        echo "Questions = 1"
    else 
        echo "Question is != 1"
    fi
}
```

Why does script return `Question is != 1`? I can't figure this out.

Update*
I'm using `script1.sh` to configure `script2.sh`. Is it possible to just get what the value of `q` is?

Comment: Do you mean to call `script1.sh` from `script2.sh`?

Comment: @chepner Yes, updated that as well as `$question` was suppose to be `$q`.

Answer (score 2):

`script1.sh` doesn't do anything if the first argument is `--source-only`, but you are sourcing the script with that argument, so `q` is never set. Drop the `--source-only` option, or change `script1.sh` to

```
if [ "${1}" = "--source-only" ]; then
    main "${@}"
fi
```

---

Answers to previous versions of the question.

`question` is a function, not a variable. Assuming you are calling `script2.sh` which sources `script1.sh`, you want to test the value of `q`, not `question`, in the `if` statement.

As an aside, the `{...}` are unnecessary in the `if` statement and its `else` clause.

Comment: Updated the question but it's still outputting `Question is != 1`

Comment: `script1.sh` only runs `main` if `$1` *isn't* `--source-only`, so `q` is not set to one in `script2.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

You never defined a variable named `question` so `$question` is the empty string. You define a function named `question` but try this:

```
foo () { echo "blah"; }
echo $foo
```

Maybe you wanted to test this `[ "$q" = "1" ]`?

Call `script1.sh` with:

```
. ./script1.sh
```

No `--source-only`. The way you have it right now passing `--source-only` ensures that `main` is not called.

Answer (score 0):

You specified `--source-only` as the first argument, no method from script1.sh will be called, and q remains an empty string. More, you are checking `$question` (not `$q`) and that doesn't take part in script at all,  hence, it is also an empty string, not "1".

Comment: How can I solve this to make the `question` function run and thus make `q=1`?

Comment: Change `"${1}" != "--source-only"` condition or script1 arguments